# Why console.log(true+1) returns 2?

Tags: javascript

I would expect something like NaN or undefined but

```
console.log(true+1)
```

clearly gives me 2.
Why?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> // Boolean + Number -> addition
>
> true + 1 // 2

And:

> // Boolean + Boolean -> addition
>
> false + false // 0

So:

```
console.log(false + 3)//returns 3
console.log(true + 3)//returns 4
```

And also:

```
console.log((true+true)*(true+true+true))//returns 6
```

Here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is very willing to convert data types. In your example it converts true to the number 1 so that it can be added to another number.

These conversions can lead to surprising results at times. See [the humorous Wat talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) for some more surprising results.

Comment: `Array(16).join("wat" - 1) + " Batman!"`... mate, thanks for that!